# Recursively find files with specific hard link count

Tags: linux, find, hardlink

I have a "tracking" directory containing hardlinks to files/dirs in a second directory ( used for tracking moves/renames). If I delete something in the original folder, no disk space is freed as its hardlink still exists. So I want to clean up this "tracking" directory periodically. Therefore I need to find all files in it, that have a hardlink count of 1.

What is the fastest way to find (and remove) recursively all files with a hardlink count of 1?

I know I can do something like `find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \+ | grep -P "^.{11}1"` and then some more piping/regexing, but this is ugly and slow. I am looking for something cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `find` there is the `-links` primary:

> `-links n`
> The primary shall evaluate as true if the file has `n` links.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html))</sup>

To find regular files that have a hardlink count of 1, use:

```
find . -type f -links 1
```

The command to remove these files is:

```
find . -type f -links 1 -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: Since you're already recommending a GNU `find` specific syntax (the trailing `+`), how about using `-delete` directly as the action instead of `-exec`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L AFAIK `-exec … {} +` [is specified by The Open Group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html). It was so [even in 2004](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html), over a decade before this answer was posted. A non-portable thing was `find -type …` instead of `find . -type …`; fixed.

Comment: Fair enough. To the best of my knowledge, though, not all systems appear to support the `+` and stick to `\;` instead. Theory vs. practice, perhaps?

Comment: @0xC0000022L The important thing is if all implementations supporting `+` support `-delete`. No, not all of them. I have just found `find` provided by `busybox` in one of my routers where `-exec … {} +` works but `-delete` does not. My point here is: if I followed your comment and switched to `-delete`, I would make the answer less portable for sure.

Comment: Fair enough. That makes sense then.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Your comment was a trigger for me to review and improve this old answer; not in the way you suggested, but still. Thanks.